# Facebook SDK Policy Issue - Android

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, privacy-policy

**I received a mail from Facebook:**

Hi,

In working to create a great Platform experience for everyone, we ask developers to ensure the apps they build comply with our Platform Policies. Your app xxx (AppId: xxxxxxxxx) doesn't comply with the following:

Platform Policy 8.1: Verify that you have integrated Login correctly. Your app shouldn't crash or hang during the testing process.

During Login, your Android app is crashing or hanging excessively, creating a broken experience for people trying to use your app. To make sure this flow runs smoothly, check that you've integrated Facebook Login correctly. We recommend that you test Login on all integrations. If you have not already done so.

Please make the requested changes by 2019-08-08 at 12:00 PST.

Let us know when you've updated your app by replying to this email. If we do not hear back from you, your app will be subject to enforcement. If you have outstanding questions, respond here and we'll do our best to help.

Thanks,
Facebook

**I have used the latest Facebook SDK in my app. Can anyone tell me how to deal with this situation. I really need some help right now.
Any help would be appreciated!**

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Did anyone find any solution?

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?